# Paymill .csv with strange timestamp

Tags: unix, csv, timestamp, paymill

When exporting my payment data from Paymill, the .csv file has timestamps in the format:

2014-09-01T10:11:01+0200

What does this mean? Does it mean the payment occured 2hrs later?

Thanks!

Comment: It is the timezone offset. see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#List_of_UTC_offsets

Answer (score 0):

at Paymill the servers use UTC time and +200 means CEST time or +100 means CET. Have a look at the normal timezone offsets.